# How to display US format date time in csv file in UK format in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, csv, date-time

I have a Windows Performance Monitor csv file that I want to view in Excel and produce charts from. The first column in the csv file is in US datetime format. e.g. `"01/12/2015 10:54:44.043"` which means January 12th, 2015 at 10:54:44.043

[image]

When I open the csv file in Excel 2010 and Custom format column A as `yyyy-mmm-dd hh:mm:ss` the data looks like this: `2015-Dec-01 10:54:44`.

[image]

Seems that Excel is not treating the first set of digits as the month, how do I format the number code to get the results I want?

Comment: Try changing the PC's Region settings temporarily, rather than Excel's settings, to mm/dd/yyyy (and its variations in long date format); record your old settings first, though, to get back to them ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date format is USA, while you are in the UK. Excel is observing the UK date format. The setting is controlled by Windows, not by Excel.

Instructions are for Windows 7:

- Exit out of Excel
- Go to Start > Control Panel
- Region and Languages
- Under Formats tab, select the `yyyy-MM-dd` to match your dataset
- Re-run Excel and import/open your CSV

Are your results different now?

[image]